# simple puppet script to copy files

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

Hi I'm new to puppet and trying to work on a sample to copy files from one location to another location. Any sample script to do that?

Ex: I've my file at d:\temp\test.txt and I want to copy this file to E:\mycopy\ folder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can "ensure" that the file at target location exists and provide the file to be copied as source in file type. A partial code snippet only showing relevant parts:

```
file { 'E:\mycopy\folder\filename':
          ensure => present,
          source => "d:\temp\test.txt",
}
```

Check the documentation of file type [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#file) and how source attribute behaves [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#file-attribute-source). Now this will work with a few caveats :

- If you are using absolute file path as source - then the file should be present on agent machine
- If you are serving file from Puppet's file server then the source file should be in appropriate location in puppet's file server.

But what is your exact purpose? Similar thing can be achieved with [`content`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#file-attribute-content) attribute of file type or [other attributes](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#file-attributes)

Comment: actually I want to copy all files from one directory to another directory. I'm not getting how to do this as I'm very new to Puppet

Comment: @jestges Directory/directory trees is same as file- use recurse attribute